# Data attributes in Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, custom-data-attribute

I know that to use CSS classes of Bootstrap we have to include the following tag in the `<head>` tag of the HTML document

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-B0vP5xmATw1+K9KRQjQERJvTumQW0nPEzvF6L/Z6nronJ3oUOFUFpCjEUQouq2+l" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

But to create many components (like carousels) Bootstrap also uses data attributes like **data-target**, **data-ride**, etc.

So my question is, the definition to use all such data attributes of Bootstrap is also defined in the stylesheet we include to use CSS classes of Bootstrap (as mentioned earlier in the question) or is there any other place where Bootstrap have defined the definition for using those data attributes which Bootstrap use??

Comment: Data attributes are used by the bootstrap.js, https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/getting-started/introduction/#js

Comment: Also use it to get help in CSS. Like [`abbr[data-original-title]`](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/6ffb0b48e455430f8a5359ed689ad64c1143fac2/dist/css/bootstrap.css#L87).